# Setting a Specific Formula for PID Controller in Simulink (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, simulink, pid-controller

I need to add a PID Controller to a Simulink Project with formula 1/(s+4.54) but I couldn't find the proper constants for the formula.

I tried looking at the different types of PID Controller libraries. I also tried finding the constants by solving the equation but couldn't.

Comment: is the question about how to implement a PID in Simulink or how to tune the PID parameters? if it is the first case, you might want to take a look at the transfer function block https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/transferfcn.html. If it is the second case, unfortunately this question does not belong to this website. You may find better luck in the  Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange for example

Comment: Thanks using a transfer function worked

Comment: i'll move the comment to an answer so that you can close the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement a PID using his Laplace domain form use the [transfer function block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/transferfcn.html)

[image]